# Installing SDL2 on Linux

Tags: linux, sdl-2

I try to run simple test.cpp from Twinklebar SDL tutorial, I get this error:

```
test.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found
```

So I look up the sdl development package in Ubuntu/Mint:

```
aptitude search sdl | grep 2
```

All I can find is this:

```
libsdl1.2-dev
```

Does this mean my only option is to install from sources?

Comment: Yes, you have to install it yourself. It's not hard, though. Take a look here : http://nothingtocode.blogspot.no/2013/07/setting-up-sdl2-in-ubuntu-or-linux-mint.html

Comment: SDL2 is available as packages in Debian unstable, testing, and wheezy-backports. I have no experience with Ubuntu or Mint, but there might be similar packages available for those distributions.

Comment: It depend on your version of Ubuntu/Mint, in the newest release, SDL2 and SDL2-image are there in the official repos, but SDL2-ttf didn't make it to get release in the official repos, you'll need to compile it yourself. If you get an older version of the distro, you'll need to compile the library yourself.

Comment: Go with compiling yourself. It's really straight forward and will enable you to have latest code fixes.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It depends which Ubuntu version you are running but yes, there is a libsdl2 package for Ubuntu: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sdl2

The package you want is called `libsdl2-dev`.

Also, about the `#include <SDL/SDL.h>` line, it seems the recommended way doing it is by adjusting your compiler flags to add SDL's include pah and use `#include "SDL.h"`. See https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=5997 for more details on that.

Comment: Thx to your answer, I whipped up this example: https://gist.github.com/dirkk0/cad259e6a3965abb4178

Comment: @dirkk0 just amazing gist!! Thanks a lot sir!

Comment: you need include so: #include<SDL2/SDL.h>

Comment: @x-rw That would work, but as the answer says, it's recommended to include `<SDL.h>` instead. You don't need `SDL2/` if you use the right compiler flags.